DB sync between SQLite and PostgreSQL (Java-Flutter)
I'm creating Java/Flutter app using PostgreSQL for server side and SQLite as local DB for client side, how can I sync those DBs effectively, so the app works both online & offline?
I found something about Powersync, a Postgres<>SQLite sync layer. But if I understood it correctly, it would send data to PostgreSQL instead of my Java API.
Is there any way to sync it but also use backend API?

By the way, SQLite was never meant to be a heavy-duty database engine like Postgres. You might do better to replace SQLite with a more serious database written in pure Java like H2.

@BasilBourque this question is about using Postgres and Java on the server with SQLite and Flutter on the client, and SQLite is by far the best option for that in my opinion. It is absolutely a "serious" database.

I understood the Question. H2 (and similar products) can run in embedded mode within the Java client. Regarding "serious", I suggest you read the linked material. The creator of SQLite, Richard Hipp, would disagree with you. To quote: “SQLite is not a replacement for PostgreSQL. SQLite is a replacement for fopen()”. I am not saying SQLite is bad, not at all;, SQLite is one of the most successful software projects in history. But users should understand its very limited purpose.

I'm in the PowerSync team. With PowerSync, downloads go "directly" from Postgres to SQLite. But for writes, PowerSync doesn't write anything directly against your Postgres database - you can write the changes using your Java APIs. It should work well for that use case.
